# Why no exists() method?

Tags: django

I send data in the view using an Ajax request:

```
def ajax_username_check(request):
    result = 'default'

    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')     

        username_req = User.objects.get(username=username)      

        if username_req.exists():
            result = '1'
        else:
            result = '0'        

    data = {'result': result}

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

As a result written to the log the following error message:

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/ajax_username_check/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/zapsum/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/zapsum/zapsum/app_accounts/views.py", line 88, in ajax_username_check
    if username_req.exists():
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'exists'
```

Why does `exists()` not work? I do everything on the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exists()` is a method on a queryset. However `username_req` is a user object, not a queryset, so you get the attribute error.

Instead of using `get()`, you can use `filter()`, which returns a queryset. You can then use `exists()`.

```
username_req = User.objects.filter(username=username)      

if username_req.exists():
    result = '1'
else:
    result = '0'
```

Another issue with using `get()` in your original code is that it could raise a `User.DoesNotExist` exception, which you are not catching.

Comment: Using get() you should also catch User.MultipleObjectsReturned exception.  [documentation for get method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get)

Comment: @koxt not in this case, since `User.username` is unique. In general, I agree, you should catch `DoesNotExist` and `MultipleObjectsReturned` when using `get()`.

Comment: I agree if OP uses not modified `django.contrib.auth.models.User`